# Export all minted code fragments to files

Tags: minted, external-files, write

I would like to export all the code fragments of a lectures book I wrote in a ordered tree structure as `<chapter>/<section>/<some name or number>.<ext>`. the code is in variuous languages (python, java, js, C, and others) and is formatted with minted in environments created with `\newminted`. Is there a way to do it in LaTeX? Thanks

(update) adding a code sample:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{needspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\lang}[1]{%
  \medskip%
  \Needspace{2\baselineskip}%
  \smash{\parbox{\linewidth}{\color{gray}\scriptsize%
    \rule[2pt]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}\\%
    \makebox[\linewidth]{\hfill\textsf{#1}}%
  }}%
  \vspace{-\partopsep}%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}

\newenvironment{code}[3]{\VerbatimEnvironment
  \lang{#2}%
  \begin{minted}[#3]{#1}%
}{%
  \end{minted}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text before the script.

\begin{code}{lisp}{$\lambda$ Lisp}{}
(if nil
  (list 1 2 "foo")
  (list 3 4 "bar"))
\end{code}

And a comment after it.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: I'm not sure if `minted` has any way to *export* code fragments like you want. Instead, wouldn't it be simpler to write the code fragments in their own files and then *import* them into your LaTeX files? `minted` has the `\inputminted` command for this purpose.

Comment: minted always writes the environment to a file then runs pygmentize on that file, so you could make a script that saves its input then runs pygmentize or modify the minted code to save a copy of each file (it uses the same filename each time so you would need to generate new filenames  with a counter)

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to process the `.tex` code with an external script/program. Depending on the organization of your LaTeX files it could be easy to extract the correct chapter and section for each code fragment.

Comment: @bonk Removing or adding chapters changes the tree structure and could be boring reflect any time changes from text to tree structure

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried to do it but can't get the right moment minted saves file before it deletes it

Answer (score 3):

The file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\makeatletter


\renewcommand{\minted@FVE@VerbatimOut}{%
  \immediate\closeout\FV@OutFile\endgroup\@esphack
  % copy not cp if using windows
  \ShellEscape{cp \minted@jobname .pyg minted-\thesection.x}%
   \setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{\value{minted@FancyVerbLineTemp}}}%

\begin{document}

\section{aaa}
\begin{minted}{python}
  a=b
  a=2
\end{minted}

\section{bbb}
\begin{minted}{python}
  x=y
  x=3
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

will leave two files `minted-1.x` and `minted-2.x` in the current directory, with the part after `-` being the section number at the point the file is written. (No checks are done so if a section has two minted blocks the earlier ones would be over-written)

The code just adds one line to copy the temporary minted file as it is written, before it is passed to pygmentize and deleted.